# Jquery ajax infinite scroll exclude footer height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm working on ajax infinite scroll. I have below code to make ajax request after scrolling at end,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
    loadlist();
}
});
```

But it fires when scrolled at end (including footer.). But I want it fired when the footer is just starting to show while scrolling (footer height is 300px).

I researched and tried following code,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - 300){ // 300px footer height
    loadlist();
}
});
```

But It seems dirty. the function gets fired too many times when scrolling. any good solutions ?

Comment: You might want to use $('#footer').height(), assuming footer has 'footer' as id might be a better practice considering height might change in future. Instead of 300.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the approach of triggering the behaviour when your footer element first scrolls into view.

```
var $footer = $("#my-footer");

$(window).scroll( function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView($footer) ) loadList();
});
```

See [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) to get the code for `isScrolledIntoView()`.